# Posting sorted json data into a Discord table?

Tags: python, json, discord

```
#remove stocks with 0 mentions
stock_with_mentions = dict((k, v) for k, v in stocks.items() if v >= 50)
#sort by value
sorted_stocks = {k: v for k, v in sorted(stock_with_mentions.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
print("STOCK MENTIONS")
print(sorted_stocks)

msg = Webhook(discordurl,msg="Stock Mentions WallStreetBets: \n\n"+str(sorted_stocks)+"")
msg.post()
```

This code so far outputs it to Discord like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/depnH6g.png]

But I want it to be a table with 2 columns like this on Discord using embeds or whatever other way there is.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you would probably generate an image like that then display the image in the embed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) to convert dictionaries into tables.

```
from tabulate import tabulate


msg_string = f'>>> `​`​`​prolog\n{tabulate(list(sorted_stocks.items()), 
             headers=("Stock Ticker", "Mentions"), 
             tablefmt="fancy_grid")}\n`​`​`​' # sorted_stocks is a dict
#send message
```

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb6vd.png) with the prolog discord markdown, you can change tablefmt argument or the discord markdown language to get different looks.